# Newbie Question: How to add common command as key mapping to .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim and I find that I am using the following command a lot: `!rspec %`. I would like to add this to my `.vimrc` file using a key mapping of something like `<leader>rs`; however, when I add the following line to my `.vimrc` it doesn't work: `map <leader>rs !rspec %`. Can someone help me correct what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `:map <leader>rs :!rspec %<cr>` do the job?

I just set up `:map <leader>pp :!apparmor_parser %<cr>` with success.

Comment: You should not use `map` here: 1) You can't know that topic starter has not swapped `:` and `;` which is common. 2) You don't want this mapping in operator-pending mode, so correct answer is `nnoremap <leader>rs :!rspec %<CR>|vnoremap <leader>rs :!rspec %<CR>`.

Comment: @Zyx, you should add your answer as an actual answer :) It looks better than mine.